# Not able to get request parameters in Filter using Java

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm trying to call a filter by passing parameters to be validated before calling my servlet. But, the request parameters are passing as null. While the same parameters are being received in my servlet. I'm not able to figure it out what could be the reason.

My call of servlet will be using window.open from Javascript.

Here is my code

```
window.open ("http://localhost:8080/SEMS/testAdd?yearFormat=yyyy", "hiddenFrame");
```

My filter

```
public class CBFilter implements Filter {

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {     

}

public CBFilter() {}

public void destroy() {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String yearFormat= request.getParameter("yearFormat");

    System.out.println("[Filter] Year Format : "+yearFormat);

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

}
```

### Web.xml

```
  <filter>
   <display-name>CBFilter</display-name>
   <filter-name>CBFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.cb.CBFilter</filter-class>     
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CBFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
```

The same request parameter is available in servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the `ServletRequest` to `HttpServletRequest` like so:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
String yearFormat= req.getParameter("yearFormat");
```

..see if that helps